# show that this proposed generalization is false.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Recall that lcm$(r,s) = rs$ if and only if gcd$(r,s) = 1$. Suppose you wish to generalize proposition 3 to:
if $a$ has order $r$ and $b$ has order $s$, then $ab$ has order lcm$(r,s)$.
show that this proposed generalization is false.

proposition 3: Let $a, b$ be elements of a finite abelian group. If $a$ has order $r$, and $b$ has order $s$, and gcd$(r, s) = 1$, then $ab$ has order $rs$.

I has thinking of taking $b = a^{-1}$ but not sure what to do after that.

Comment: In fact, in a non-abelian group, you can have elements $a, b$ of order 2 but $ab$ has any order you want, including infinite.

Comment: @T.Bongers: In order to show that the generalization is false you're going to need to pick two elements that don't satisfy the hypotheses of the original theorem.  So it's a *good* thing that the orders aren't relatively prime.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the additive group modulo $6$. Then $2$ has order $3$, and $4$ has order $3$, but $2+4$ has order $1$.

If you prefer to multiply, look at the objects $1,2,4,5,7,8$ under multiplication modulo $9$. Then $4$ has order $3$, and $7$ has order $3$, but $4\cdot 7$ has order $1$.

Note that these two examples are essentially the same, and are particular cases of your construction, since (second example) $7$ is the inverse of $4$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a$ has order $r \neq 1$.  If you take $b = a^{-1}$ then $b$ has order $s = r$ and $ab = 1$ has order $1$, which by assumption is not equal to $r = lcm(r, r)$.  So what you have done is correct.  All that was left was to observe that your proposed generalization is not satisfied by these two elements.